# View is not rendering in android 5.1.1 devices but working perfect on below versions

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, sencha-touch-2

I have developed cross platform app with sencha framework.I have targeted  it for android API 22 which is 5.1.1 and with Cordova 5.0.0 .Works perfectly fine with 5.0.2 device but in 5.1.1 it doesn't render its view just shows a blank white screen after splash screen ,no idea on whats going wrong please little help is appreciated .
One wired senario :When run the app on 5.1.1 device and lock the phone at app initialize and when unlock the phone after some time  the view is rendered .

Comment: paste ur code where app loads first page.

Comment: Also having this exact problem. Using apportable.